# Macro not found in libgcrypt on Centos 7

Tags: c, linux, makefile, macros, centos7

I have a C program that uses *libgcrypt*.
I put this string in the builder to install the libraries for Centos 7:

```
yum -y install json-c-devel expat-devel libpcap-devel flex-devel automake libtool bison libuv-devel openssl-devel libgcrypt-devel
```

and no problem come out.

Unfortunately, the compilation of the code terminate with an error caused by a macro cannot be found:

> error: 'GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_GCM' undeclared (first use in this function)

The macro is inside the **libgcrypt** for sure, so I really don't understand how cannot be found at all.

If I compile the same code in Debian, it works well and the macro is resolved properly.

**P.S.** My system is Debian 8 and I use docker for Centos 7

Comment: What's the version of `libgcrypt` on your Debian ?

Comment: Does your program actually `#include` the appropriate header file for gcrypt?  More generally, do edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: on Debian, libgcrypt20, and yes, I include properly the header file

Comment: "*The macro is inside the libgcrypt*": Macros are *never* defined in libraries, but always in source files, in this case typically in headers coming with the development packages to the libraries.

Comment: @alk I wanna say that, of course, I mean in the header file.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is very difficult to create a minimal example to reproduce that. The problem is not inside a standalone program. But I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CentOS-7` uses `libgcrypt` and `libgcrypt-devel` version 1.5 (patched), which seems to not include `GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_GCM` declaration.

Looking at the git commits, it seems to have been available in 1.6+.

https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=libgcrypt.git;a=commit;h=90cce18b9eced4f412ceeec5bcae18c4493322df

On a newer version, you would see a line in `/usr/include/gcrypt.h`, like the following:

```
GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_GCM      = 9,   /* Galois Counter Mode. */
```

Comment: Thanks. So it seems the only way is to install the 1.6 (or more) for Centos ?

Comment: Yeah, or get one that's already built and compatible, for example in Fedora(22).
http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/